# How do I combine features like word embeddings and sentiment polarity for text classification using LSTM neural networks?

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, feature-extraction, text-classification, word-embedding

Embeddings layer of LSTM is fed with the weights=embedding_matrix from the vocab, and model.fit has X_train which is the tokenized text data.
My X_train has shape (12,000 , 100) and embeddings_matrix has shape (34613, 300) where 34613 are the number of tokens(vocab from complete data ~15000 sentences).

I created a sentiment_matrix associating a polarity -1/0/1 with every word of shape (34613, 1).

Given the sentiment polarity is a per word information(just like embeddings are), how do I prepare the sentiment feature, and how to give this as input to the neural network?

I looked up the keras functional API https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/ 
But I couldn't get it to work, so please help.